# Bad respond when trying to get authentication token for Reddit api 'Application Only OAuth'

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, reddit, reddit-access-token

So i been trying to get access to the reddit api.

I registered to reddit. verified my mail. opened an app and got my credentials.

[Followed this official documentation](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#application-only-oauth) and also came across to [this tutorial](https://ranjithnair.github.io/2018/02/27/Reddit-Application-Oauth.html)

All my efforts have failed and don't get any respond.

I am using nodejs. but also tried in postman and failed.

Tried 2 options using fetch and using axios:

```
    const axios = require('axios');
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { URLSearchParams } = require('url')



class RedditApi {

    clientId2 = "get ur own credentials by opening an app here https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps";
    clientSecret2 = "get ur own credentials by opening an app here https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps";

    authenticationUrl = `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token`;

    BASE_URL = 'https://www.reddit.com/';

    tokenAuth = null;
    tokenExpirationTime = null;

    currencyObj = null;

    constructor(currencyObj) {
        this.currencyObj = currencyObj;
        console.log("constructor service")
    }

    async getAuthToken() {

        const bodyParams = new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: "https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client",
            device_id: "DO_NOT_TRACK_THIS_DEVICE"
        });

        console.log(this.clientId2, 'this.clientId');
        debugger;

        const headersObj = {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${this.clientId2}:`).toString('base64')}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        };

        let response = null;
        try {
            response = await axios.post(this.authenticationUrl,
                bodyParams,
                {
                    headers: headersObj
                });
            debugger;
        } catch (error) {
            debugger;
            console.error(error);
            console.log(error.stack);
            return null;
        }
    }


    async getAuthToken2() {
        try {
            // Creating Body for the POST request which are URL encoded
            const params = new URLSearchParams()
            params.append('grant_type', 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token')
            params.append('device_id', 'DO_NOT_TRACK_THIS_DEVICE')

            // Trigger POST to get the access token
            const tokenData = await fetch('https://oauth.reddit.com/grants/installed_client', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: params,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${this.clientId2}:`).toString('base64')}` // Put password as empty
                }
            }).then(res => {
                debugger;

                return res.text()
            })
            debugger;

            if (!tokenData.error) {
                debugger;

                res.send(trendingResult)
            }
            res.status(tokenData.error).send(tokenData.message)
        } catch (error) {
            debugger;
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = RedditApi;
```

when using axios i get this respond: "Request failed with status code 401"

When using fetch i get this respond:  "'

## 403 Forbidden

\nRequest forbidden by administrative rules.\n\n'"

Anybody knows what is the problem and how can i fix it?
Many thanks!

Comment: _"You must supply your OAuth2 client's credentials via HTTP Basic Auth for this request. The "user" is the client_id, the "password" is the client_secret."_ - I don't see you supplying the password portion in `Basic ${Buffer.from(\`${this.clientId2}:\`).toString('base64')}`

Comment: (And why are you using this convoluted way to provide the credentials in the first place, axios takes an `auth` option for that, https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config)

Comment: @CBroe that did the trick! thank you! i was following this tutorial https://ranjithnair.github.io/2018/02/27/Reddit-Application-Oauth.html and some other in youtube and they said yo leave the password empty. also looked at the official docs.  i guess thing have changes

Comment: @CBroe reddit api want you first to get the auth token and only then make the request. not sure if what u r suggesting is possible in this case.

Comment: I am just talking about a different way to provide the HTTP Basic Auth credentials, you don't have to assemble them in `username:password` format, apply base64 encoding and then stuff the whole thing into a header yourself - you can simply provide an object `auth: { username: '...', password: '...' }` in the request options, and axios will handle the rest for you.

Comment: I get what u said now. tried it and it work. once again thank you!